Being logged in with a Google account automatically recreates Stack account
This has started recently happening on my work Mac with Google Chrome.
I am logged in my work Google account.
When I browse Stackoverflow it automatically creates an account, no confirmation or nothing.
Sometimes when I go to profile -> delete account -> delete it immediately creates a new account after I complete the deletion.
It takes data from Google which is a security issue!

Did you previously log in with that Google account? Third-party applications can not use your information without explicit consent. (That's literally impossible, the Google sign-in wouldn't hand out that info)

Yes it's allowed but I deleted my Stack account. It shouldn't create an account without my confirmation.
Maybe I need to clarify? I am not talking about Google side. I'm talking about Stack side.

Stack Overflow does not know when you gave permission to use your google account.
When loading a page, it communicates with Google's SSO system, which says:
"Yeap, you can get some info on this user!"
Then SO logs you in, or creates an account with that information.
It creates an account because there are a LOT of SE sites that work under the same authentication system, and they're all linked together. SO just assumes that your previously existing SE account needs another account on the site you're currently login in to. If you do not want it, you need to disallow SO in Google.

I disagree. While it is still allowed to gather information from Google as the user did not disallow SO. That doesn't mean that Stack should take it as intent to create a user account. And to create it without any confirmation by the user.
You can see this especially if you delete the account and after the redirect happens upon completion of the deletion, it directly creates a new account.
So you just pressed delete and on the next page you have a new account. That doesn't make any sense.

@steros The fact that you deleted the account means that there's no data stored about your account... Not even the fact that you used to have an account that is deleted, is stored. So how would SO know you don't want to create an account using the SSO method that you authorized SO to use? You'll need to revoke that authorization. That's not a matter of opinion, that's just how the system works.

"It takes data from Google which is a security issue!" I mean, this is Google... giving away and taking data you'd like to be kept private is kind of their thing.

I don't understand the negative reception here; it seems exceedingly odd that an account would automatically be recreated without any prompting, in any case. I'd instead expect it to work like navigating to any Stack site for which you don't have an account, with the "join" button in the navbar, which you have to explicitly click to create an account. Deleting your account should bring you back to that state, no matter your login provider.

I don't know if this only affects SO or not. I'm using a Google account to log in, and I've just deleted my account on [3DPrinting.SE] (the site I always used for testing account deletion) this week, and I didn't get a new account created after that.

Probably related to "Google one-tap": Upcoming changes to sign-up flow on the Stack Exchange network "Over the last couple of months, we’ve conducted several experiments surrounding some changes to the sign-up flow on Stack Overflow, all of which we’ve successfully graduated in some fashion on Stack Overflow."

Thanks @AndrewT. I'll view to close this here as it doesn't seem productive. I posted an answer there.

@zcoop98 What negative reception? Are you talking about the votes? Meta posts that make big assumptions from the get-go are pretty much downvote magnets. You've been on meta long enough to know that votes are not based on quality or usefulness but on how people feel about it.

@Cerbrus "Stack Overflow does not know when you gave permission to use your google account." They should revoke any permission when an account is deleted SO side, or at least prompt for confirmation before creating an account. There's no way in GDPR terms that you need to make a convoluted operation to avoid a system REcreating an account for you without confirmation of express consent.

@Tensibai I'm pretty sure the permission is SE-wide. It's not subsite-specific. And you don't need to tell me what SO should do... I can't change that. I'm just here to try to explain how it currently works.

@Cerbrus fair point, sorry :) Just this sounded a bit dismissive about the report here, I find it legit and still find SO (the company) is kinda out of line according to various legislations with this behavior.

Little surprised at the downvotes here. No one thinks that this might be some kind of really bad bug, or even a nefarious way for StackExchange to artificially puff up its 'new user' count? This does not seem right to me at all. It could lead to terribly misleading information, for not only SE staff, but for investors as well!

@ouflak Since it was being run as an A-B test, there were plenty of people who were unable to reproduce, making it unclear to them what the author is talking about.

@Cerbrus - Regarding this statement "Stack Overflow does not know when you gave permission to use your google account." - it may be true, but the original grant happens at the Stack Exchange network's request so there is an opportunity to store that event timestamp.

Yes, there is, @EatenbyaGrue... That doesn't change how it currently works, though.

@Cerbrus - I'm not disagreeing with you but but just curious, how do you know that this data isn't stored anywhere? Are you one of the devs?

Educated guess, @EatenbyaGrue. When you open a new site, SE asks Google's SSO: "Do you have user information I have access to?" At that moment, SE doesn't know who you are or what your email is, so it can not know if / when you have given access in the past. All SE gets in return is "No"  or "Yeap, this is his data"

This question is also being referenced on Meta - 45000 new signups in the last two weeks! @gparyani, I still say this is very fishy.

If we're only considering a single site, this only re-creates an account if you already have one. I'm still wondering whether, if you've logged in to one site, will this automatically create accounts for you on other sites, or not? I'd like to see that clarified to understand the scope of this behaviour.

@SPArcheon-onstrike you're voicing your opinion on how the site should work. Frankly, that doesn't matter to me. In the comments here, I was explaining how it worked, at that very moment. How you agree or disagree with that implementation is irrelevant, and pinging someone 4 months later to voice your disagreement with that implementation isn't constructive. What do you expect from me? I haven't even voiced whether or not I agreed with that implementation. "Don't shoot the messenger". I'm not the one you should be voicing your disagreement at.

@SPArcheon-onstrike I'm not "Rationalizing". I was explaining the (at that time current) implementation. That's just context. No opinion, no workarounds. Your dislike of that implementation is not something you should be directing at me. You don't need to write an extra comment to state you're gonna stop replying. Just.... Don't reply.

Came here after noticing a recent post on the main Meta site referencing this issue. If the described issue is still happening then IMHO it is useless to argue if this is intended behavior by design (we are not fools, there is no way you can tell us that it is intended that deletion of an account just recreates it immediately afterward due to a redirect) nor reason about what the actual implementation that caused the issue may be.
The only real question is why this has been ignored so far and how this fits in the "increase user retention, force new accounts" drama.

There seems to be some related bug to this. I'm forever logged in and yet just now when visiting the main page, some pop-up starts to whine about logging in with Google. Which I don't want since I am already logged in and never logged out. It just popped up once and I can't reproduce it.
Using Firefox and a bunch of ad and tracking blockers.

Also reported on MSE.

If you give Stack Exchange permission to access your Google credentials to create an account then you'll get an account.
If you don't want that to happen, all you have to do is rescind that Google permission or alternatively delete the connection from the Stack Exchange side before you delete your account.

Shouldn't (also?) the "Google" entry be removed from the 'My Logins' page on 'MSE', like explained in the 'Help Center'...? // Well "also", or would already do the job...? // Or the info mentioned in this Answer could/should also be mentioned in the 'Help Center', I think, as there is no mention of any specific action to perform on the 'Google' side for a 'Google' Login.

Deleting an account shouldn't remove the login method. That method might well be used by different accounts.

I guess I'm still confused as to why login methods wouldn't always be account-specific, and therefore rescinded automatically on account deletion? That sounds extremely odd to me; I can't fathom any case where you'd intentionally want to keep login methods around for deleted accounts (at least ones which weren't attached to another already?).

@zcoop98: They are, specific to your SE account.

@Cerbrus Okay, that's the bit I was missing, that makes sense. Still seems like a bug that new accounts are being added without confirmation, however.

Sorry I won't accept this answer. As I explained in the comments already, it shouldn't create an account without even asking once "do you want to create an account linked to your Google account". Also this behavior only recently changed.

@steros and even if the company will try to claim this is "by design", surely the other behavior you described can't be considered correct. The redirect after a delete request should NOT have the effect of recreating the account you just deleted. I hope the company won't try to call this a reasonable behavior since it would be pretty preposterous... but to be honest, I don't expect a reply in the first place... this is just too "good" for the "artificial userbase inflation" campaign, can't give it up.
